# Rendering Latex on Hugo websites with MathJax

Tags: latex, markdown, render, mathjax, hugo

I have a Hugo website:

http://cnr.lwlss.net/post/autoregression/

Latex used to render correctly on pages like the above, but currently does not.  I don't understand what has changed.

When setting up the Hugo site, I followed the instructions to run [MathJax with Hugo](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/#mathjax-with-hugo) from the Hugo documentation.  Hugo generates pages with the code below, which seems correct.  Yet Latex now doesn't render.

Can anyone please explain what I need to change to get MathJax back running under Hugo?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
     inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
     displayMath: [['$$','$$']],
     processEscapes: true,
     processEnvironments: true,
     skipTags: ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre'],
     TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" },
            extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js"] }
  }
});
</script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
     // Fix <code> tags after MathJax finishes running. This is a
     // hack to overcome a shortcoming of Markdown. Discussion at
     // https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/199
     var all = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax(), i;
     for(i = 0; i &lt; all.length; i += 1) {
          all[i].SourceElement().parentNode.className += ' has-jax';
     }
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Seems that deleting the final block of code gets things back up and running again.  For example, [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/L10cjve7/1/) renders correctly, whereas [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/L10cjve7/) does not.

Maybe Hugo docs need to be updated?

Comment: The configuration block goes before the call to MathJax.js. Also, 2.7.1 is very old; try 2.7.5.

Comment: Certainly updating to 2.7.5 made no difference.  Happy enough deleting that block for now.

Comment: Changing content file extensions from `.md` to `.mmark` helps with Katex, perhaps it'll help with MathJax too.

Comment: The configuration block is needed since MathJax does not configure `$` delimiters by default (and the page you link to only has equations with `$` delimiters).

Comment: But it's the other block, the MathJax.Hub.Queue block that seems to cause the problem?

Comment: The code in the second block as `&lt;` where it should have `<` (scripts in HTML are CDATA automatically, so you don't need to escape special characters).  Perhaps that is the problem?  Changing it in your jsfiddle example allows it to work.

Comment: Aha!!  Thanks @DavideCervone. Unfortunately making sure I have written `<` instead of `&lt;` in Hugo partial template does not make my Hugo pages render correctly.  I lazily copied the above from the HTML output rendered by Hugo.  I now think that Hugo converts `<` to `&lt;` when rendering the pages and that breaks the second block.

Comment: @CnrL, I suspect you are correct that Hugo is the culprit.  You will have to check the documentation to see if there is a way to prevent that, or work out a method that doesn't use `<`.  Perhaps something like `while (jax = all.pop()) { jax.SourceElement()...}` would do it.